# Is the post body of the Stack Exchange data dump sanitized?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

I am building a project based on the Stack Overflow data dump.

As per [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) the `Body` of `Posts` / `PostsWithDeleted` is given as rendered HTML and not Markdown.

Is this HTML sanitized?

Comment: Sanitized as in how?   There wouldn't be anything else in the body that could execute, but there *may* be some CSS style classes that are expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that HTML is sanitized. It is the same rendered HTML that we serve when you view the page live on our website, cached so that the HTML doesn't have to be rendered from Markdown every time the page is loaded.

As part of our rendering process, we sanitize any HTML that users provide by stripping all elements [not on this allow list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites), including any with attributes we do not support.